# 955 Gates of Heaven - תתקנ"ה רקיעים

Tags: sources-mekorot, mysticism-kabbalah, heaven

I have come across the concept of "955 Gates of Heaven". I know it is currently doing the rounds with regards to a controversy, and thus I heard it in a news article, but have had trouble finding any information about it.

So far [this](https://www.sefaria.org/Maaseh_Rokeach_on_Mishnah%2C_Seder_Kodashim%2C_Kinnim.12) is the only (legitimate) reference I can find. Has anyone got a more detailed source for me to look up (from traditional/orthodox/authentic sources only please)? Even better, an introduction, systematization, context and derivation. Best of all, some sort of explanation, jargon-reduced/free?

EDIT: [Another lead](https://shvilei.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/translation-devarim-57732.pdf) (thanks @Shmuel):

> Rabbi Avraham Galanti in Kol Bochim (Eichah 2, 21), that there are
> 955 firmaments. This number corresponds to the numerical value  of the
> word ם“השמי ,meaning the heavens. (Note: this calculation is  based on
> a system that values a final letter “mem” as 600.)

See the article for a lot more information! Still, would be nice to know more.

[Has anyone got Kol Bochim? You don't have to provide an answer to the question necessarily, but please at least confirm if he goes into any further detail, worth me purchasing the sefer?]

Comment: Rabbi Meir Papirash says that the four elements we have (earth, water, air and fire) has a total gematria of 955.

Comment: I was introduced to these articles in my most recent question, and found that they also wrote some on this topic. See: https://shvilei.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/translation-devarim-57732.pdf

Comment: this keeps happening @Shmuel, what is this the 3rd or 4th time we've been in the same sugya at the same time coincidentally?

Comment: Wonderful. Nothing happens without a reason :)

Comment: See paragraph 2 of subject רקיע from Sefer Kehillat Yaacov by Rabbi Yaacov Tzvi Yolles. Here's the link: https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=44143&st=&pgnum=265

Comment: קול בוכים is on Otzar I believe.

Comment: Here is a link https://oraita.net/devarim/about/ sharing similar ideas to what Shmuel posted and another here is the Aderet Eliyahu which I think gives another idea: https://www.sefaria.org/Aderet_Eliyahu%2C_Deuteronomy.32.1.3?lang=bi