# Getting close to G-d by studying sefer Devarim

Tags: sources-mekorot, chassidic-rebbe, deuteronomy, parshat-devarim

Rav Elimelech Biderman [(Torah Wellsprings, parashas Devarim - Tishah B'av 2017, p. 16)](https://www.parshasheetsarchives.com/_files/ugd/87a86f_e15ea585c46f447caf997a03d6b8f6b6.pdf) quotes the Kotzker Rebbe and says that whoever studies sefer Devarim, becomes close(r) to Hashem.

> "Even a Yid [RebYehudi] who isn't close [semuchim]to Hashem the entire year,can become close to Hashem when he studies chumash Devarim."

**In what context is the Kotzker Rebbe teaching this idea? What exactly does he say and why especially focused on sefer Devarim?** (Please include original location of source from Kotzker, since I haven't found it using the words on Otzar HaChochmah).

Any ideas where this can be found and why he writes this?

Comment: This sound related to the 955 words for 955 worlds inyan, just not sure if this is what the Rebbe had in mind?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/133882/955-gates-of-heaven-%d7%aa%d7%aa%d7%a7%d7%a0%d7%94-%d7%a8%d7%a7%d7%99%d7%a2%d7%99%d7%9d

Comment: I remember that yes. Don't see how this relates though.

Comment: By the by, I originally started teaching Chumash after I heard three mechanchim (one man, two women) say that they really don't like teaching Devarim - because it's like a long musar shmooze. Be good, don't be bad, worship Hashem, don't worship Avodah Zarah. Hard to teach indeed. So my first class was Sefer Devarim.

Comment: perhaps this can be in connection with studying the entire Sefer Devarim during Shavuot?

Comment: One might say Sefer devarim was the first musser given to the Jewish people and thus gives insight on how to better yourself in avodas Hashem

Comment: @Dude That's sounds plausible. Since I haven't find the Kotzker's original explanation, I don't know if he uses that exact same idea though.

Comment: Might it have to do with the minhag to read the entire Dvarim on Hoshana Rabbah night?

Comment: @NaftaliTzvi I don’t know to be honest…

Comment: No one? Seems to be a tough one :)

Comment: @MichoelR just saw your awesome comment again, and realise I only +1'd it, I didn't reply to it. Nothing to say other than - awesome!

Comment: @RabbiKaii, thank you. I think what I said was obvious, once you've seen it - but it still leaves a lot of room for an explanation! I don't consider this question really answered: What was the Kotzker's point?

Comment: @MichoelR Thanks and yes :) Still haven't found the original words and meaning behind the Kotzker's words.

Answer (score 3):

The ultimate source is [Yevamos 4a](https://sefaria.org/Yevamot.4a.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):  "Even according to the one who does not generally derive homiletic interpretations from juxtaposed verses [semuchim], he does derive them from Devarim." The Kotzker's statement seems to be a Chassidic drasha on the geamara's use of the word סמוכים = nearby.

It would still be good to have a source on the Kotzker's statement itself.

"How does one become closer to G-d by studying sefer Devarim?" That is not the question. It's part of the Torah, of course a person becomes closer to G-d by studying it. The question is, What point is he making about sefer Devarim?

Comment: This is more of a comment.

Comment: @N.T. so is yours. It makes sense, but could be greatly improved by providing sources.

Comment: @MichoelR TY. That's exactly what I meant. Why especially Devarim?

Comment: Well, as for the gemara in Yevamos, see the Mahartz Chayos and others there, who explain that Devarim was one long presentation by Moshe Rabbeinu, so it is understandable that neighboring parts will be more connected than in the rest of the Torah. How that connects to the Chassidische vort - I'd love to know that!

Comment: Yours doesn't say anything about Devarim specifically, which is the question.

Comment: @N.T. Don't know what you mean. It's right there in Yevamos.

Comment: As you said, the gemara in Yevamos is not talking about the Kotzker Rebbe's vort.

Comment: @N.T. You said it backwards. The Kotzker Rebbe's vort is a Chassidic play on the gemara.