# Locating this Rokeach on sefer Devarim

Tags: sources-mekorot, parshat-devarim

I have been told that the Rokeach, in his introduction to sefer Devarim, writes that

מספר משנה תורה - MiSefer Mishneh Torah shares the same gematria (1386) as סמוכים לעד לעולם עשויים באמת ויושר - They stand fast for ever and ever, done in truth and uprightness. [(Tehillim 111:8)](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.111.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).

Where exactly can this Rokeach be found? I have searched but could not find it unfortunately. Also, what exactly does it mean, that these two are related through having the same gematria?

[Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.111.8?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en) on this posuk in Tehillim explains that:

> Steadfast are His commandments, supported by might, strengthened with punishments and warnings, and the chapters are set one next to the other in sequence and to expound on them. This is what Solomon said (Song 5:15): “His thighs are pillars of marble, etc.”

But I don't see the connection it has with "MiSefer Mishneh Torah".

Edit: thanks to @Harel13 for pointing to the sefer that has it. If anyone could explain what the Rokeach means, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to prove by quoting the Rashi?

Comment: @Dov my own way to trying understanding this. I looked into that Rashi, because in sefer Devorim, we also find the Tocheichah (Devorim 28 for example). Rashi says "strenghtened with punishments", so that's why.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/136050/getting-close-to-g-d-by-studying-sefer-devarim?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

It's from the Rokeach's book Sodei Razei Smuchim ([link](https://tablet.otzar.org/#/book/143645/p/13/t/827980/fs/muMMBSv3YbyncfpOmhP8TBnj245zR2jZtMk6kIPaXYmP/start/0/end/41/c)).

He seems to be clarifying a statement in [the gemara](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Yevamot.4a.4?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi&p2=Berakhot.21b.9&lang2=bi) regarding learning ideas via juxtaposition of certain words and verses (smichut) in the Torah. One view in the gemara is that there are ideas to be learnt via juxtaposition. Another view is that there aren't, except with regards to Devarim, AKA Sefer Mishneh Torah. The Rokeach is apparently explaining why even according to those who disagree with the notion of smichut, it can still be learned in Devarim - because of the stated gematria connection. The Rokeach's book, however, seems to follow the first opinion, and presents Smichut concepts from the entirety of the Torah.

For general information regarding the book, see [here](https://forum.otzar.org/download/file.php?id=68538) (PDF link).

Comment: Wow, much appreciated Harel. I am also wondering what he means.

Comment: @Shmuel see my edit, I think I got it now.

Comment: Greatly appreciated. One more, last thing, what is the connection of סמוכים לעד לעולם עשויים באמת ויושר - They stand fast for ever and ever, done in truth and uprightness. (Tehillim 111:8) with that Gemara and the explanation of the Rokeach?

Comment: @Shmuel the verse was [quoted](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Yevamot.4a.2?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi&with=Berakhot&lang2=en) a few lines prior in the gemara to show that there is a concept of smuchim.

Answer (score 1):

The question posed from [Yevamot 4a](https://www.sefaria.org/Yevamot.4a.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) is how do we learn the principle of homiletical interpretation from the Written Torah? Where is the source for this style of Torah study?

Rabbi Elazar says that we learn this from the posuk in [Tehillim, chapter 111:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.111.8?lang=bi) which says:

> סְמוּכִ֣ים לָעַ֣ד לְעוֹלָ֑ם עֲ֝שׂוּיִ֗ם בֶּאֱמֶ֥ת וְיָשָֽׁר׃

What the Rokeach is pointing out in [ספר סודי רזי סמוכים](https://tablet.otzar.org/#/book/143645/p/13/t/827980/fs/muMMBSv3YbyncfpOmhP8TBnj245zR2jZtMk6kIPaXYmP/start/0/end/41/c) is that the gematria of: עשוים באמת וישר, which is 1,385, when including the Kollel totals 1,386.

And that this is also the gematria of: מספר משנה תורה which totals 1,386.

In other words, the source for this type of Torah explanation in the Written Torah according to Rabbi Elazar is found in Sefer Devarim, which is called Mishneh Torah.

Comment: "the source for this type of Torah explanation in the Written Torah according to Rabbi Elazar is found in Sefer Devarim" - is this because in sefer Devorim we review what is stated in the earlier books (hence the name Mishneh Torah) or does this mean that the explanation for this Gemara can be found in a posuk in sefer Devarim? Sorry for my misunderstanding this.

Comment: @Shmuel As I understand the language from Yevamot 4a, Rabbi Elazar is saying the Midoraita source for the principle of homiletical interpretation is found somewhere in sefer Devarim. It does not detail how specifically that is learned out, only that it is there.

Comment: sorry for my ignorance, but what is kollel when we speak about gematria?

Comment: @Shmuel Good question. It is including more in the count for the whole word or phrase. The concept is found everywhere in this type of teaching and is based upon the general teaching from Moshe Rabbeinu about the relationship between VaYakhel ויקהל and Pekudei פקודי.

Comment: hmm, this might would be a good next question. Do you know where I can read more about this? I am not familair with the exact rules of gematria, I usually go by the method of the Baal HaTurim.